# remove NSNumberFormatter hyphen

Tags: swift, nsnumberformatter

i am using this code,

```
var number:NSNumber = NSNumber .numberWithInteger(mylabel.integerValue)
        var numberFormatter : NSNumberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.SpellOutStyle
        numberFormatter.formatterBehavior = NSNumberFormatterBehavior.BehaviorDefault
        self.displyingLabel.text = numberFormatter .stringFromNumber(number)
```

if enter this number - 8555

the output shows " eight thousand five hundred
 fifty-five "
I want to remove the hyphen in the output, Is there any way in which we can remove the hyphen and replace it with an "and". Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean: [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-"
                                     withString:@" and "];

Comment: You may have to do what Watsche suggested. I'm not seeing anything in NSNumberFormatter's documentation that indicates that this can be changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *str = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(number);
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString: @" and "];
```

can be also a one-liner, if you wish.